# How to allow only 2 decimal value in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, decimal

Friends, I'm using a datagridview in my vs 2005 windows application. In the datagridview for column 3 and 4, I want to allow user to enter decimal value upto 2(like 19.88 or 29765.01). How can I restrict it to 2 decimal places? And also if the user enters ".1", it should be converted to "0.10"  .Any suggestion will be of great help. I've already made that column to accept only digits and single decimal(.).

EDIT:Here is my code. The program flow is not going inside the if clause.I've given value 7889.6655 in the cell.It should not allow me to write beyond 7889.66   :

```
    Regex reg = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{1,2}$");
    Regex reg1 = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2}$");

    if(reg.IsMatch(dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgViewColumn.TOTAL_TCS].Value.ToString()))
    {
      if (!reg1.IsMatch(dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgViewColumn.TOTAL_TCS].Value.ToString()))
      {
          dgView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgViewColumn.TOTAL_TCS].Value += "0";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To your bound column add attribute DataFormatString="{0:n3}"

In case you are using Eval then <%# Eval("NumFailedFiles", "{0:n3}") %

Comment: datagridview is not of bound type. I'm populating it through code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like below right,

```
            Regex reg = new Regex("^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
            if (reg.IsMatch(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString()))
            {

            }
```

EDIT:

I have tested the below code for a textbox, it is working fine. Put the datagridview's row value instead of textbox.text in the following code.

```
        Regex reg = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{1,2}$");
        Regex reg1 = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2}$");
        if (reg.IsMatch(textBox1.Text.ToString()))
        {
            if (!reg1.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
            {
                textBox1.Text += 0;
            }
        }
```

EDIT2:

In the else case you can write some thing like below

```
        Regex reg = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{1,2}$"); 
        Regex reg1 = new Regex("^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2}$");
        if (reg.IsMatch(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
        {
            if (!reg1.IsMatch(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value += "0";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please, provide a valid value");
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value = "";
            return;
        }
```

Comment: oh! its a small thing, put the 0 as "0" ok. Or post your code in your question, i will see it and correct

Comment: @Sukanya, its going if it is valid only. Put an else case and clear the value by showing one text message to the user and dont allow until all the values in the row is filled up.

Comment: It's working in the following manner.If user enters 78.666 then it shows the message and clears the field.If user enters 78.66 then it doesn't show any message.My requirement is it'll not allow the user to enter the 3rd digit after decimal(.).can it be done?

Comment: @Sukanya, if it should be done there should be some e.Cancel property. But it will not present in this eventargs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to restrict the user to up to two decimal places with the standard DataGridView column types.  To do this right you'll need to create your own `DataGridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn` which extends the standard `DataGridViewColumn` and hosts a Winform MaskedTextBox as its editing control.

I've successfully done with using these resources:

[DataGridViewColumn Hosting MaskedTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox)
[DataGridView Custom Column Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

However, if you simply want to format the values in a column to display two decimal places you can set your `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`'s [`DataGridViewCellStyle.Format` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) to "N2".  You can also format a column's data in your DataGridView's [`CellFormatting` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) handler.